# Check whether data is present in another matrix and if so, replace it

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, vectorization

In Octave, have matrices as such:

```
abc = [1 2 3; 5 7 8];
def = [5 7 9; 10 11 12];
```

I would like a function which, for all [x y z1]s in abc, checks whether there exists a [x y z2] in def, and if so, replaces it.

So, I want something like

```
checkandreplace(abc, def);
```

which changes abc to [1 2 3; 5 7 9]

EDIT:

The best I could come up with is a looping scheme:

```
for i = 1:size(abc, 1)
   index = find(ismember(def(:, [1 2]), abc(i, [1 2]), 'rows'))
   if(index)
      abc(i, :) = def(index, :)
   endif
endfor
```

Can it be done in a better way?

EDIT:

Forgot to add that it should be stable, i.e. it shouldn't change the order of rows in abc.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's wrong with your loop?

Comment: Nothing wrong! I just wanted to know if vectorization can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the whole thing in a single call to `ismember`:

```
[m,I] = ismember(abc(:,1:2), def(:,1:2), 'rows');
abc(m,:) = def(I(m),:);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but it works =)

```
abc = [1 2 3; 5 7 8];
def = [5 7 9; 10 11 12];

abc(find(ismember(abc(:,1:2),def(:,1:2),'rows')),:) = ...
def(find(ismember(def(:,1:2),abc(:,1:2),'rows')),:) 
abc = 
    1    2    3
    5    7    9
```

## EDIT:

If abc is sorted, you can sort it afterwards, using [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html).

Comment: Please check the last edit, your code changes the order for this case:

    abc = [1 2 3; 5 7 8; 13 16 19; 23 27 45]
    def = [5 7 12; 1 2 9]
    abc(find(ismember(abc(:,1:2),def(:,1:2),'rows')),:) = ...
    def(find(ismember(def(:,1:2),abc(:,1:2),'rows')),:)
    abc =

        5    7   12
        1    2    9
       13   16   19
       23   27   45

Comment: @user34812 if abc is sorted why not just sort it again. `sortrows(abc,[1 2])` would sort abc first for the first column, then for the second.

Answer (score 0):

here's my "vectorized" solution, no for loops or if conditions, and **it should keep the original order:**

```
[x y]=find(squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@eq,permute(abc(:,[1 2]), [3 2 1]),def(:,[1 2])),2)==2));
abc(y,:)=def(x,:);
```

testing :

```
abc =
     1     2     3
     5     7     9
```

is it faster?  You can test and see...